# MySQL-python is not installing in windows 8

Tags: python, mysql, django

While trying to install mysql db for django(1.8.x) using command prompt it shows this error:

error: command 'C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Micro
osoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Maybe this error is too straightforward but I can't figure out that.

Python version is 2.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL-python driver needs the binding for MySQL in order to compile, build and install.

On Linux and other systems; it is easy to get a build environment going because these operating systems provide packages to setup a development environment that include all the required libraries to compile and build software.

To install the driver you would have to install the Python source code, and the developer libraries for the MySQL client. On Linux and other systems this is a straightforward process - but on Windows is requires a lot more setup than what is typically done on developer machines.

Therefore, most projects provide a pre-built installed for Windows or a wheel that can be installed without compiling things.

For MySQL-python, the Windows installer is available at the [downloads page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have got my answer.